# Zoom controls for Android TableLayout?

Tags: android, fonts, size, zooming, tablelayout

I couldn't find a proper way to implement the Zoom Controls for the TableLayout.
I am thinking about redrawing the table with different font sizes to achieve the zoom effect, is it a good approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by zoom control on a table view? do you want to have control over the text size?

Comment: Yes text size or the over all tableLayout size is fine too. I want to provide a good tablelayout for the viewer.